# ¿Cómo desplegar el nombre de los empleados junto con la fecha en la que faltaron?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada **empleados**:

| no_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Jorge |
| 002 | María |

Y la tabla llamada **registros**:

| no_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-12-01 |
| 002 | 2021-12-01 |
| 001 | 2021-12-02 |
| 002 | 2021-12-01 |
| 001 | 2021-12-03 |
| 002 | 2021-12-06 |
| 002 | 2021-12-07 |

La tabla **registros** contiene el número del empleado junto con la fecha en la que tiene asistencia; lo que quisiera detectar son los días en los que los empleados estuvieron ausentes (que son las fechas que no contiene la tabla **registros**).

En el ejemplo expuesto anteriormente, ambos empleados asistieron los días 01 y 02 de diciembre; María faltó el día 03 y Jorge faltó el día 06 y 07. Los días 04 y 05 fueron fin de semana, por lo que no se consideran faltas ya que son días no laborales (los días laborales son de lunes a viernes).

Lo que busco es obtener un resultado en el que se despliegue número del empleado, su nombre y la fecha en la que faltó:

| no_empleado | nombre | falta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Jorge | 2021-12-06, 2021-12-07 |
| 002 | María | 2021-12-03 |

Por ahora, lo único que he logrado es desplegar las faltas de un sólo empleado con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fecha) as falta FROM 
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) fecha FROM
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-07' AND fecha NOT IN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%Y-%m-%d') FROM registros WHERE no_empleado = 001 AND fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2022-12-07') AND DAYOFWEEK(fecha) BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

Con la consulta anterior genero una tabla con todas las fechas; posteriormente la comparo con mi tabla de registros para obtener las fechas (entre el 01 y 07 de diciembre) que no están capturadas en las asistencias y establezco a un empleado en particular para finalmente obtener las fechas en las que faltó dicho empleado:

| falta |
| --- |
| 2021-12-06, 2021-12-07 |

¿Cómo puedo adaptar mi consulta para dejar de requerir el filtrado por empleado y desplegarlos a todos con sus respectivas fechas en las que faltaron?

Estoy trabajando con MariaDB en phpMyAdmin. Varios me han recomendado la utilización de CTE (WITH, específicamente), pero phpMyAdmin no trabaja con CTE.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHPMyAdmin estás utilizando? Según mencionaron en [un comentario en una issue de su repo](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/331#issuecomment-841815429), se agregó soporte para `WITH` en la [versión 5.5.0](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/pull/334).

Comment: ¿No es mejor discriminar mediante los `NULL` usando un `LEFT JOIN`? No entiendo mucho para que son todos esos `UNION`  ¿? No parecen necesario para lo que quieres.

Comment: @padaleiana, me parece que esa versión está en etapa de prueba, aún no existe una versión estable disponible. Estoy trabajando con la versión 5.0.1

Comment: Mala mía: me refería a la versión 5.5.0 de [sql-parser](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser).

Comment: ¿Eso tiene que resolverse con SQL o hay algun lenguage de programación que se pueda usar para conseguirlo?  Digamos PHP por ejemplo.

Comment: @masterguru, de preferencia con SQL, aunque precisamente estoy utilizando PHP en el lado de la programación y no veo cómo se pueda hacer en PHP

Comment: Fíjate en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516561/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-los-registros-de-una-base-de-datos-de-los-usuarios-que-no-ingresar/516605#516605) pues pedian algo parecido a lo tuyo.  Si no te sirve te responderé algo similar para tu caso específico, pero con la misma idea.

Answer (score 4):

Deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT e.no_empleado,
       e.nombre,
       GROUP_CONCAT(v.fecha) as Ausencias
       FROM empleados e
       CROSS JOIN (
             (SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) fecha FROM
             (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
             (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
             (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
             (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
             (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) 
        ) v
        left join registros r
             on r.no_empleado = e.no_empleado
             and r.fecha = v.fecha
        WHERE v.fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-07' 
              AND DAYOFWEEK(v.fecha) BETWEEN 2 AND 5
              AND r.fecha IS NULL
        GROUP by e.no_empleado,
                 e.nombre
```

La tabla principal es la de `empleados` y la de las fechas generadas que debe unirse mediante un `cross join`, teniendo todas las fechas por cada empleado solo resta ver cuales faltan en `registro` para saber cuales son las ausencias.

Ver [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b02d48d056e64ea309fe47453f52a600)