# ¿Cómo mostrar los registros de una base de datos de los usuarios que no ingresaron datos de un día especifico día en especifico con PHP?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, datetime, datagrid

Tengo que realizar una consulta a una base de datos y "desde ,hasta"  lo cual ejecuto bien con el siguiente codigo

php

```php
$consulta = $con->query("SELECT * FROM  `usuarios` WHERE `data` BETWEEN '$busqueda11'AND'$busqueda98'ORDER BY `data` ASC ");

while($row = $consulta->fetch_array()){ ?>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nome"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nomel"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["data"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orarioi"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orariof"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["tot"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nomel1"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orarioi1"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orariof1"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["tot1"];?></div>
    <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["notas"];?></div>
    <div class="botones">
```

Pero solo muestra los dias que los usuarios llenaron un formulario de registro, y necesito que muestre todos los dias("DESDE","HASTA") y todos los uasuarios que no ingresaron datos con el valor predeterminado

Comment: Diria que esa consulta ya te muestra todos los registros que estan en esa tabla entre esas fechas... a menos que tengas otra tabla con más datos de esta dudo que consigas nada mas

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta !! exacto pero tengo que mostrar los que no ningun usuario registra nada con el valor predeterminado !! digamos que me muestra del 1 al dia 3  Y si no hay registro el día 2, no me m muestra nada !! como puedo hacer para que me muestre el día 2  ... suponiendo que dia "1 es presente",  "2 (ausente valor predeterminado)", "3 presente"

Comment: Eso lo debes hacer desde el PHP que recorra esos registros recuperados de la base de datos. Edita la pregunta pulsando sobre [edit] y agrega el PHP para ver como lo estas haciendo ahora para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: **data** que tipo de campo es?  una fecha?  fecha y hora?  ¿se puede repetir por usuario? es decir, ¿puede ser que un usuario tenga dos registros con la misma fecha?

Comment: tipo de campo "varchar", es solo fecha ! puede repetirse

Comment: y que formato tiene esa fecha?   dd-mm-aaaa?  aaaa/mm/dd? otro?

Comment: exacto , dd-mm-aaaa

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo... tal como lo tienes ahora cada vez que haces el ciclo se imprime cualquier usuario de cada fecha... y es probable que alguno si que haya estado "presente" en una fecha pero no en otra, y otro al reves, ¿cierto?  Entonces ¿tu quieres detectar eso o quieres detectar en que fechas **ningún** usuario estuvo "presente"?  Deberias poner una minitabla o relación de ejemplo de lo que quieres de salida en la pregunta, porque ahora estoy confundido.

Comment: exacto si un dia el usuario no se registra no me aparece nada, y quiero que aparezca el usuario con los campos predeterminados !

Comment: Vamos, que quieres que te lo hagamos todo, pues lo que has puesto tu en la pregunta es bien poco comparado con lo que hay que hacer... deberias esmerarte un poco más en la pregunta y presentar un [example] de lo que estas haciendo y que errores te da... "no se hacerlo" no es un error.  No has hecho practicamente nada, o al menos en la pregunta no se ven ni los valores por defecto y lo que pides es mucho curro, la verdad. De este modo lo único que puedo hacer por ti es simplemente decirte lo que necesitas hacer, pero lo haces tu.

Comment: 1) Usando DateTime en PHP averigua como conseguir la diferencia de dias entre la fecha inicial y la final. 2) Usando esa diferencia crea un array con **todas** las fechas y guardalo para despues 3) Cuando recorras la consulta tan solo crear dos arrays, uno que contenga como clave la fecha, y como valor el registro entero, y el otro array con la clave que contenga el usuario y como valor de nuevo el registro entero. 4) Luego puedes recorrer el array con clave de fecha con un bucle foreach y mediante un condicional usando in_array() averiguas si hay algun registro para esa fecha.

Comment: disculpas por la explicación tan corta no quería generar eso justamente que me lo hagan !! queria una idea  de como lo podría hacerlo, no tengo un error de código hasta ahi pero no se como puedo realizar esa tarea y no se me acurre !

Comment: 5) En el **else** de ese condicional pones otro foreach que recorra el array del usuario, y dentro, mediante otro condicional miras si hay algun registro coincidente en la fecha del primer foreach, y si lo hay escupes todo ese html, y si no lo hay pones los valores por defecto. Y mas o menos ya esta... seguro que me dejo algo, pero si llegas hasta alli puedes volver a preguntar con todo eso hecho y te volveremos a ayudar

Comment: muchisimas gracias probare eso !!!

Comment: Ya tienes la explicación... repasa bien los puntos uno a uno y ves haciendolos poco a poco... es un poco lio por tanto bucle pero dada la consulta que haces milagros no se pueden hacer... suerte!

Comment: Uf, perdon, cuando llegues al punto 3 parate y no lo hagas y no continues con el resto, me he equivocado, asi no es como debes seguir... vuelve entonces con los puntos 1 y 2 resueltos y ya te quedara menos, pero lo que viene despues es más complejo de lo que he dicho.

Comment: Cuando regreses con esos dos puntos hechos, y vuelvas a formular la pregunta, expon claramente lo que quieres de salida, con un ejemplo bien claro de la tabla o tablas de salida que quieres conseguir, porque creo que el lio que tienes empieza alli, en que no sabes exactamente lo que quieres mostrar y como lo quieres mostrar, y eso es fundamental para que te puedan ayudar.  Muestralo claramente en tu siguiente pregunta, gracias y suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí adjunto lo que hice, sin comprobar, para que lo tengas de referencia, y lo pruebes a ver si te funciona. El código está comentado.

```php
// valores por defecto
$array_campos_defecto = [
    "nome"      => "desconocido",
    "nomel"     => "desconocido",
    "data"      => "desconocido",
    "orarioi"   => "desconocido",
    "orariof"   => "desconocido",
    "tot"       => "desconocido",
    "nomel1"    => "desconocido",
    "orarioi1"  => "desconocido",
    "orariof1"  => "desconocido",
    "tot1"      => "desconocido",
    "notas"     => "desconocido",
];

// función que generará la salida HTML para cada registro
function genera_salida_html($array_fecha)
{
    global $array_campos_defecto;
    foreach ($array_fecha as $fecha => $row) {
        foreach (array_keys($array_campos_defecto) as $clave) {
            $salida .= '<div class="table__item">'.$row[$clave].'</div>';
        }
        $salida .= '<div class="botones">';
    }
    return $salida;
}

///////// ALGO ////////////

// creamos dos objetos DateTime
$dt_inicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $busqueda98);
$dt_final   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $busqueda11);

// calculamos el número de dias
$num_dias   = $dt_final->diff($dt_inicial)->format("%a"); //3

// creamos un array de fechas posibles dia a dia
$array_fechas = [$dt_inicial->format('d-m-Y')];
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_dias; $i++) {
    $array_fechas[] = $dt_inicial->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('d-m-Y');
}

// ejecutamos la consulta
$consulta = $con->query("SELECT * FROM  `usuarios` WHERE `data` BETWEEN '$busqueda11' AND '$busqueda98' ORDER BY `data` ASC ");

// creamos un array multidimensional en función del usuario y de la fecha
while ($row = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
    $por_nome[$row["nome"]][$row["data"]][] = $row;
}

// recorremos todas las fechas
$salida = '';
foreach ($array_fechas as $fecha) {

    // recorremos todos los usuarios
    foreach ($por_nome as $nome => $nome_data) {

        // si la fecha de este ciclo esta entre las fechas del usuario
        if (in_array($fecha, array_keys($nome_data))) {

            // y si la fecha del usuario coincide con la fecha actual
            if (key($nome_data) == $fecha) {

                // agregamos html a la  salida con los datos de la fecha
                $salida .= genera_salida_html($nome_data[$data]);
            }
        } else {

            // si la fecha no existe para este usuario aplicamos valores por defecto
            // pero cambiamos uno de ellos para que se vea de que usuario es
            $array_campos_defecto['nome'] = $nome;

            // agregamos html a la  salida con los datos por defecto para este usuario
            $salida .= genera_salida_html([$fecha => $array_campos_defecto]);
        }
    }
}

echo $salida;
```