# ¿Como hacer un busqueda de tal fecha a tal otra ! que te muestre los datos registrados ,y solo el nombre y la fecha del que no registro datos?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Este es el código que tengo, pero no se como mostrar los nombres de los usuarios que no registraron actividad ej (domingo)... este codigo "solo me trae los que registraron algo en esa fecha" y debo mostrar, todos los usuarios día por día de las fechas de la búsqueda y los que no registraron nada que muestre solo el "nombre" y la "fecha". Dejo una imagen del resultado esperado !(agregue los campos en forma manual, para hacer una imagen del lo que se espera) !!

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['enviar1'])) {
    $busqueda11 = $busqueda1;
    $busqueda98 = $busqueda12;
    
    //consulta para traer los nombres de los usuarios
    $consultaNom = $con->query("SELECT DISTINCT `nome` FROM  `usuarios`");
    //consulta de fecha a fecha 
    $consulta = $con->query("SELECT * FROM  `usuarios` 
        WHERE `data` BETWEEN '$busqueda11'AND'$busqueda98'ORDER BY `data` ASC ");

    while($row = $consulta->fetch_array()){ 
    ?>
        <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nome"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nomel"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["data"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orarioi"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orariof"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["tot"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nomel1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orarioi1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["orariof1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["tot1"];?></div>
            <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["notas"];?></div>
            <div class="botones">
            <a style="text-decoration:none;background-color: #4488EE;"class="botones1" 
                href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row["id_usuario"];?>">Aggiungi nota
            </a>
            <a style="text-decoration:none;background-color: #4488EE;"class="botones1" 
                href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row["id_usuario"];?>">Eliminare
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php 
    } 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ara ara, usando italiano, muy bien, `DISTINCT`, me hace alusion a que tu tabla lo que hace es llevar un registro o historial de lo que han hecho los usuarios, y es por esto que el nombre puede repetirse varias veces, ahora bien, existe el inconveniente de que si seleccionas informacion en un rango de fechas y en ese rango no se ha hecho registros, por obvias razones no te va a traer lo que necesitas, es este el problema con el que te enfrentas actualmente cierto?, en este caso quieres que si no hay registros en esa fecha, te muestre la informacion basica de ese usuario y el resto vacio.

Comment: Vacio o con los valores por defecto, asi que solo para estar seguros, es esto lo que necesitas?

Comment: wauuuu es exactamente lo que necesito!! y se que es algo complejo o muy complejo para mi .... si alguien me podría ayudar estaría super agradecido . el usuario y la fecha y los demás campos vacíos !! para que muestre que ese dia ... tal o cual usuario no registro nada !

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo mostrar los registros de una base de datos de los usuarios que no ingresaron datos de un día especifico día en especifico con PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516561/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-los-registros-de-una-base-de-datos-de-los-usuarios-que-no-ingresar)

Comment: Has duplicado la pregunta. En su dia finalmente te contesté en esta, pero no se si es que no lo vistes o no te funcionó: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516561/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-los-registros-de-una-base-de-datos-de-los-usuarios-que-no-ingresar/516605#516605

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de intentar realizar el ejercicio estuve pensando un poco y resulta que no tiene mucho sentido que puedas traer una fecha sin haber un registro entre las fechas que necesitas, es decir, no puedes mostrar algo que no existe.

Pense en que quizas querrias mostrar entonces es la fecha mas proxima a ese rango de fechas pero que no lo abarca.

Sin embargo esto ultimo no es tan sencillo, es un poco mas dificil de lo que parece si es lo que quieres...

Sin embargo propongo la siguiente solucion parcial por el momento.

En caso de que especifiques de mejor forma que fecha deberia devolverse en caso de que el usuario no haya hecho cambios en ese rango de fechas podria volver a editar mi respuesta y ver si la logro adaptar.

Entonces para la solucion del problema he creado el siguiente ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    pr.nombre,
    MAX(NM.data) as data,
    NM.actividad
FROM pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT nombre, MAX(data) as data, actividad FROM pr
    WHERE pr.data BETWEEN '2022-03-10' AND '2022-03-16' GROUP BY pr.data
) as NM 
ON NM.nombre = pr.nombre GROUP BY pr.nombre;
```

**Notese que las fechas estan hardcodeadas aqui, pero serviran tal cual una vez reemplaces esos valores en tu codigo.**

Donde la base de datos se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y su tabla llamada `pr` posee los siguientes elementos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el resultado de la consulta `SQL` se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde vemos que en la tercera fila nos trae `NULL` en los dos ultimos campos, esto es debido a que el usuario existe, pero la ultima fecha que registro no esta en el rango, por lo tanto devolvemos el usuario pero su informacion en ese rango no existiria, ya que no habria una fecha ligada.

Ahora bien, forzar la devolucion de una fecha (aun no se exactamente cual), implicaria que en esta parte de aqui:

```
SELECT
    pr.nombre,
    MAX(NM.data) as data,
    NM.actividad
```

Modifiquemos con una condicion un tanto mas compleja, que datos de que tabla quiero consultar, ya que si en una no existen los datos existiran en la otra, una solucion particular y sencilla para no complicarse tanto es seleccionar las fechas de ambas tablas y ver cual vas a usar:

```
SELECT
    pr.nombre,
    MAX(pr.data) as data_p,
    MAX(NM.data) as data,
    NM.actividad
```

Donde la tabla `pr` en tu caso seria la tabla `usuarios` mientras que la tabla `NM` es una tabla resultado de una sub consulta para concatenar la informacion.

Donde la tabla `NM` esta creada con una consulta que se ve asi:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nombre, MAX(data) as data, actividad FROM pr
    WHERE pr.data BETWEEN '2022-03-10' AND '2022-03-16' GROUP BY pr.data
```

Y trae en este caso los ultimo registros que estan en el rango de fechas descritos por ti.

Y con ayuda de un `LEFT OUTER JOIN` lo que hacemos es concatenar ambas tablas devolviendo los valores de la tabla de la izquierda y los registros que coincidan con los de la tabla de la derecha.

Esta relacion se hace con el campo `nombre` de ambas tablas:

```
ON NM.nombre = pr.nombre
```

Por ultimo agrupamos todos los registros por `pr.nombre`, ya que si no nos aparecerant todos los registros asociados a la union de ambas tablas y que cumplan con la condicion.

Entonces basicamente lo que debes hacer para adaptar esta consulta a tus necesidades es:

- Reemplazar los nombres de las tablas por los tuyos
- Para aquella informacion en la que requieras que este aunque no existan registros en el rango de fechas debes seleccionar la informacion desde la primera tabla (ya que esta no esta limitada a las fechas), un ej es el campo de `nombre`.
- Para aquella informacion que necesitas que sea cargada y que cumpla la condicion de que esta en tu rango de fechas debes usar la segunda tabla (ya que ésta esta limitada a informacion en ese rango de fechas).
- Si requieres valores de ambas partes puedes seleccionar ambos campos y ponerles un alias para distinguirlos usando la palabra reservada `as`.
- Añade y quita los nombres de las columnas que necesites segun la estructura de tu tabla y los datos que quieras cargar.

**NOTA**:

Al usar un `JOIN` estamos obligados a que se cumplan dos condiciones principalmente para no generar errores:

- Siempre debe haber una relacion entre una tabla y otra (tabla1.valor1 = tabla2.valor2)
- Uno de los campos a relacionar debe ser alguno de los campos de la tabla que va a usar el `JOIN` y el otro debe ser de otra tabla, por ej: `LEFT JOIN tabla ON tabla.nombre = ...`

Comment: No se si depronto es lo que necesitabas, pero por el momento es en lo que he logrado pensar, ya que aun no me cuadra lo de la fecha...

Comment: primero ... la verdad no se como agradecerte en verdad !... que gente con tu conocimiento se tome el tiempo para explicarle a principiantes como yo habla muy bien de ti y de esta comunidad .... mire la respuesta y dije wauuuu !!!  ahora es lo que pensaste en primer lugar !! si no hay datos de alguien entre las fechas de busqueda, en lugar de no mostrarlos me piden que muestre el nombre y la fecha !! se que es lo mismo que no traerlo ! pero entregue mi primer trabajo y me piden esto que para mi es imposible !!1 he realizado todo lo demas y lo que pense que seria facil no lo puedo realizar !

Comment: por ejemplo si nadie registro nada el fin de semana y mi búsqueda abarca el fin de semana , me tendría que mostrar todos los nombres que hay en la tb con la fecha del sábado y si el domingo todos menos uno se registraron me tiene que mostrar a todos con la fecha del domingo y los datos de registro, y el que no se registro el nombre, la fecha del domingo y los campos en blanco  !

Comment: por ejemplo en la imagen que adjunte !!! el primer nombre seria lo que tengo que generar, que no esta en la base de datos(sacar el nombre de la base de datos y agregar las fechas en las que se realizan la busqueda ) ...el segundo !!! como registro datos muestra lo que hay en la base de datos !!

Comment: Lo bueno es que segun la consulta que hice, tienes acceso ambos datos si los necesitas, aunque... ahora que lo pienso yo lo colocaria alguna condicion mas como para que no traiga tanta informacion... es que quien esta pidiendo esa clase de informacion no es muy logica al respecto la verdad, no posee mucho sentido, es decir, hay mejores formas de realizarlo y esta logica solo es aplicable para casos especificos aterradores.

Comment: En caso de querer mostrar una fecha especifica y segun las especificaciones que das... la fecha que debes retornar varia segun eso de acuerdo a demasiadas condiciones... en ese caso lo mejor seria hacer lo siguiente pienso yo: realizar la consulta y mostrar los datos que posean una fecha con su informacion, en caso contrario mirar si el campo es `NULL` pero desde el propio `PHP`, donde dentro de `PHP` mismo podrias encargarte de agregar ese campo con la fecha requerida, ya que el tiempo que se delimita no posee como tal una marca diferenciable o estable de tiempo.

Comment: Un ej del porque digo que la logica de ese ejercicio es aterradora es porque la unica forma que hay de poder mostrar los usuarios aunque no hayan registrado algo en el rango de fechas es seleccionando todos los usuarios de la tabla de manera unica y luego hacer una union y pues... si son 7000 registros cargara unos 2000 o 3000 por lo menos... por eso no es que sea muy viable que se quiera mostrar el nombre aunque no haya un registro de un usuario ligado con el nombre... :c, una forma de mejorarlo es mostrando los ultimos X, pero esto te quitara los X + 1 usuarios para arriba.

Comment: Tratare de pensar en una forma de enfocarlo mas a ello que necesitas, ya que en parte si es lo que necesitas, en parte no, pero no veo posible ni tampoco muy viable eso de las fechas sin llevar a la base de datos al limite xd.

Comment: entiendo me parece tan absurdo como a ti !!! pero no so muchos usuarios es para sistema de registro de un cafe !!! asi que a lo sumo tendra 20 / 30 nombres !! no mas ! ! no pude convencerlos de q lo que me pidieron es absurdo pero .... insisten que se vea el nombre, la fecha y nada en los campos si no hay registros !